# Python Dot Separator with Variable Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, converters, separator

I'm currently attempting to write a program that takes in a user input of units and magnitude and converts them to a user defines the unit. So basically just a unit converter (still doing beginner projects with Python).

But for the module `pint`, it uses a dot separator as the way to get the units, like so:

```
from pint import *

ureg = UnitRegistry()
dist = 8 * ureg.meter
print(dist)
>>> 8 meters
```

Now 8 is tied to meters. But say I want to let the user define the unit. So have a variable defined by an input attached to `ureg` like so:

```
from pint import *

ureg = UnitRegistry()
inp = input()
>>>inp = meter 
unit = ureg.inp # this is a variable defined by user
step = 8 * unit
print(step)

>>>AttributeError: 'UnitRegistry' object has no attribute '_inp_'
```

The problem is python thinks I'm trying to access an attribute called `inp` from `ureg`, which doesn't exist. if `inp=meters`, why won't it work as `ureg.meters` worked? How can you attach variables to call attributes from a module?

Comment: `8 * getattr(ureg, input())` ?

Comment: @UltraInstinct yeah didnt know about that one, learned something new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`getattr(object, name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
ureg = UnitRegistry()

user_value = input()
unit = getattr(ureg, user_value) # this is a variable defined by user
step = 8 * unit
print(step)
```

Comment: Yep this did it. Didnt know about `getattr()`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
ureg = UnitRegistry()
user_value = input()
unit = vars(ureg)[user_value] # this is a variable defined by user
step = 8 * unit
print(step)
```

Or:

```
eval('ureg.%s()'%user_value)
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept getting errors on the first part, got the second one to work! What does `eval()` do?

Comment: @U9-Forward Wrong, `eval` evaluates a python expression. Anything from `1 + 1` to `os.system(MALICOUS_CODE)`. It's a security risk, and it exposes your program to vulnerabilities, as well as unwanted errors.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Yeah i know, it is bad practice to use `eval` and `exec`, from here it explains all:[Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)